Solid Queue isn't processing jobs in queues
I'm using the Solid Queue library to send emails. I followed the instructions provided in it's README file and videos from the GoRails & Webcrunch. Once the database is setup with Solid Queue tables I created a Job class that commits the jobs to a table once I trigger perform_later:
WishBirthdayBuddyJob.set(wait_until: Time.now + 1.minute).perform_later

It returns:
TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SolidQueue::Job Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "solid_queue_jobs" ("queue_name", "class_name", "arguments", "priority", "active_job_id", "scheduled_at", "finished_at", "concurrency_key", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING "id"  [["queue_name", "default"], ["class_name", "WishBirthdayBuddyJob"], ["arguments", "{\"job_class\":\"WishBirthdayBuddyJob\",\"job_id\":\"3afbb65b-616d-40cf-acaa-78f92508bb14\",\"provider_job_id\":null,\"queue_name\":\"default\",\"priority\":null,\"arguments\":[],\"executions\":0,\"exception_executions\":{},\"locale\":\"en\",\"timezone\":\"UTC\",\"enqueued_at\":\"2024-07-07T07:11:54.335187513Z\",\"scheduled_at\":\"2024-07-07T07:12:54.312752723Z\"}"], ["priority", 0], ["active_job_id", "3afbb65b-616d-40cf-acaa-78f92508bb14"], ["scheduled_at", "2024-07-07 07:12:54.312752"], ["finished_at", nil], ["concurrency_key", "[FILTERED]"], ["created_at", "2024-07-07 07:11:54.367836"], ["updated_at", "2024-07-07 07:11:54.367836"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SolidQueue::Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "solid_queue_jobs".* FROM "solid_queue_jobs" WHERE "solid_queue_jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SolidQueue::ScheduledExecution Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "solid_queue_scheduled_executions" ("job_id", "queue_name", "priority", "scheduled_at", "created_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING "id"  [["job_id", 5], ["queue_name", "default"], ["priority", 0], ["scheduled_at", "2024-07-07 07:12:54.312752"], ["created_at", "2024-07-07 07:11:54.387819"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  commit transaction
Enqueued WishBirthdayBuddyJob (Job ID: 3afbb65b-616d-40cf-acaa-78f92508bb14) to SolidQueue(default) at 2024-07-07 07:12:54 UTC
 =>
#<WishBirthdayBuddyJob:0x0000707f33d8bf58
 @_halted_callback_hook_called=nil,
 @_scheduled_at_time=2024-07-07 07:12:54 327945/1048576 UTC,
 @arguments=[],
 @exception_executions={},
 @executions=0,
 @job_id="3afbb65b-616d-40cf-acaa-78f92508bb14",
 @priority=nil,
 @provider_job_id=5,
 @queue_name="default",
 @scheduled_at=2024-07-07 07:12:54 327945/1048576 UTC,
 @successfully_enqueued=true,
 @timezone="UTC">

The job is successfully queued and ready to run after I start listening to it with:
bundle exec rake solid_queue:start

But this doesn't output anything in console, the cursor just blinks on the next line. After a few seconds I hit Ctrl+Z to stop execution (Ctrl+C doesn't output anything):

config/solid_queue.yml is initialized by Solid Queue on setup. I haven't changed anything to it:
default: &default
  dispatchers:
    - polling_interval: 1
      batch_size: 500
  workers:
    - queues: "*"
      threads: 3
      processes: 1
      polling_interval: 0.1

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default

I also setup an active job adapter as solid queue in the development environment. In it's GitHub repo I couldn't find anything related to this. I deleted the database and re-ran migrations but the result is the same. I restarted my Terminator and laptop. I created a new Rails app and integrated Solid Queue but the result is the same, however on Ctrl+C it returns:
^C/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.7.3-x86_64-linux/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.7.3-x86_64-linux/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
    from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.7.3-x86_64-linux/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:42:in `to_a'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in internal_exec_query'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:1028:in `block in with_raw_connection'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/null_lock.rb:9:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:1000:in `with_raw_connection'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:33:in `block in internal_exec_query'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:1143:in `log'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:32:in `internal_exec_query'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:61:in `exec_delete'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:208:in `delete'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:25:in `delete'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:624:in `_delete_record'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:1198:in `_delete_row'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:1194:in `destroy_row'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:197:in `destroy_row'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:125:in `destroy_row'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:783:in `destroy'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:423:in `block in destroy'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:110:in `run_callbacks'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:952:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:423:in `destroy'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:305:in `block in destroy'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:365:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:535:in `block in within_new_transaction'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/null_lock.rb:9:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:532:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:344:in `transaction'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:361:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:305:in `destroy'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:797:in `destroy!'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/app/models/solid_queue/process.rb:29:in `block in deregister'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue.rb:59:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/app/models/solid_queue/process.rb:28:in `deregister'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/processes/registrable.rb:27:in `deregister'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:239:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:602:in `block in invoke_after'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:602:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:602:in `invoke_after'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:111:in `run_callbacks'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/processes/poller.rb:38:in `block in start_loop'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue.rb:59:in `instrument'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/processes/poller.rb:37:in `start_loop'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/processes/poller.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/processes/runnable.rb:16:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:124:in `block in start_fork'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:123:in `fork'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:123:in `start_fork'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:65:in `block in start_forks'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:65:in `start_forks'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/supervisor.rb:12:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/solid_queue-0.3.3/lib/solid_queue/tasks.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:188:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block in top_level'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:147:in `run_with_threads'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:132:in `top_level'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:214:in `standard_exception_handling'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/gems/rake-13.2.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/bin/rake:25:in `load'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/bin/rake:25:in `<main>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

This wasn't the case for my existing project. I'm using Ruby 3.3.1, Rails 7.1.3.4, SQLite 1.7.3 (litedb adapter in Fly.io).
database.yml:
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem "sqlite3"
#
# `Litesupport.root.join("data.sqlite3")` stores
# application data in the path `./db/#{Rails.env}/data.sqlite3`
#
# `Litesupport.root(env).join(path)` stores
# application data in the path `./db/#{env}/#{path}`
#
# idle_timeout should be set to zero, to avoid recycling sqlite connections
# and losing the page cache
#
default: &default
  adapter: litedb
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  idle_timeout: 0

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Litesupport.root("development").join("data.sqlite3") %>

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Litesupport.root("test").join("data.sqlite3") %>

# Warning: Make sure your production database path is on a persistent
# volume, otherwise your application data could be deleted between deploys.
#
# You may also set the Litesupport.root in production via the
# `LITESTACK_DATA_PATH` environment variable.
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Litesupport.root("production").join("data.sqlite3") %>

Why does this happen?


But running this command doesn't output anything in my console

That is because it won't. It does not print anything to console (by default anyway).
Also be aware that solid_queue:install will only set solid queue as adapter for production by default, you need to add it manually to development environment or it will use async adapter by default (which runs in the server process). Starting the solid queue supervisor will do nothing then as it has no jobs


Hey there!  Actually it does print couple of lines when running solid queue supervisor and the reason I know that is because I have seen in both of the videos that I have given link of! And yes I forgot to mention that I have set up active job adapter as solid queue in development environment. I ran many jobs manually from rc while running supervisor in other terminal window. But still no output at all!

@JuzerShakir I think it used to be that way but it will now log to rails logger by default but will not display it, at least that's what I see with current edge rails. It writes to log/development.rb but it will not show in the server process nor in the solid queue one

You're right! I got caught up with that and it made me think that my worker is not listening and executing jobs but it was. Since I had SQLite db, I opened SQLite database software and opened the db and it showed all the jobs I had executed. And I also found a very cool & better solution to add plugin: solid_queue to the puma.rb file that will not only execute the job but also show logs to the console in both development & production env! :)
